# using forEach to apply a function to each array item in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand how forEach works in Javascript

```
var arr = [5,4,3,2,1];

var square = function(x){
   return x * x;
}

arr.forEach(function(item){
     item = square(item);
});
```

I should get `[25, 16, 9, 4, 1]`. But get `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 4):

`item` is just an argument to your callback function (that works like a local variable) and modifying it does not change the array - it is not the actual array element.  The next two arguments to the callback give you the array and the index so you could modify the actual array element.

```
var arr = [5,4,3,2,1];

var square = function(x){
   return x * x;
}

arr.forEach(function(item, index, array){
     array[index] = square(item);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/L8598/

---

You may want to note that `.map()` is made for producing a new array for operations like this:

```
var arr = [5,4,3,2,1];

var square = function(x){
   return x * x;
}

var newArray = arr.map(square);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/C226B/

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not collecting the results in any variable. The variable `item` is being changed in the local scope of function. To get that result outside you have to collect that in a variable.

Do like bellow

```
var arr = [5,4,3,2,1];
var result = [];

var square = function(x){
   return x * x;
}

arr.forEach(function(item){
     item = square(item);// 
     result.push(item);
});
```

Seems like for your above situation `map` is a better solution

```
 arr.map(square) //will return expected result.
```

Comment: Don't push to `result` manually when there's a dedicated function to do this.

Comment: @Bergi ya I've told that solution also, but I should tell what is fault with current problem, and how to overcome that.

Answer (score 0):

`item` is a local variable, assigning to it does not alter the array. To modify the array, you'd have to assign to the property `arr[i]`, for example

```
arr.forEach(function(item, i) {
    arr[i] = square(item);
});
```

However, what you really want to do is a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that won't modify anything, but produce a new array of the results:

```
new_arr = arr.map(square);
```